# MySQL taking two values, getting a new value and sorting by it

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have two columns in MySQL table (x and y). What I want to do is to subtract x from y making it z and then sort the resultset by z.

Sample data:

```
| ID |      NAME | X |  Y |
---------------------------
|  1 |  DemoUser | 0 |  5 |
|  2 | DemoUser2 | 2 | 10 |
```

Desired output:

```
| ID |      NAME | X |  Y |  Z |
--------------------------------
|  2 | DemoUser2 | 2 | 10 | -8 |
|  1 |  DemoUser | 0 |  5 | -5 |
```

Comment: Please post your tables' structures, sample data and desired result. That might help you get your answer faster.

Comment: Any data is fine I just need to know how to subtract to tables name that value z and then tell mysql sort by Z

Comment: Do you want a SQL solution? TBH, i would consider doing this with PHP.

Comment: I am going to use PHP I'm going to run this query through php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on sample data you provided

```sql
SELECT t.*, t.x - t.y z
  FROM table1 t
ORDER BY z
```

Sample output:

```
| ID |      NAME | X |  Y |  Z |
--------------------------------
|  2 | DemoUser2 | 2 | 10 | -8 |
|  1 |  DemoUser | 0 |  5 | -5 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75efe/1)** demo.